My nftables firewall allows ipv6 input on specified ports for a short while, but then blocks
I have a moderately complex ruleset, running on Debian 12, but it includes simple rules to open e.g. ports 80 and 443 (implicitly for both ipv4 and ipv6). Immediately after running "systemctl restart nftables", a port scan shows the ports open and listening. They can also be accessed by e.g. telnet.
But within about a minute, the ports become blocked according to port scan and no connections can be made to them.
What should I be looking for to fix this?
EDIT: Since asking the basic question, I have done many more tests and set up a new VPS using Ubuntu 24.04 to get a later version of nftables. The problem continues to exist. The ruleset has been reduced to a bare minimum, and I can't think of much else to try. The problem is not specific to ports 80 and 443, and here I have been testing port 22. With nftables stopped, I can submit mail to Postfix. With nftables running, I cannot connect after about a minute. The test ruleset is:
table inet firewall {
    chain input {
            type filter hook input priority filter; policy accept;
            ct state { established, related } accept
            iifname "lo" accept
            icmpv6 type { destination-unreachable, packet-too-big, time-exceeded, parameter-problem, echo-request, mld-listener-query, nd-router-solicit, nd-router-advert, nd-neighbor-solicit, nd-neighbor-advert } accept
            ip protocol icmp icmp type echo-request ip saddr 127.0.0.1 accept
            ip6 nexthdr tcp tcp dport 25 accept
            ip protocol tcp tcp dport 25 accept
            tcp dport 22 ip saddr 82.43.121.238 accept
            udp dport 60000-61000 ip saddr 82.43.121.238 accept
            log prefix "nftables input dropped: " flags all counter packets 242 bytes 12885 drop
    }

    chain forward {
            type filter hook forward priority filter; policy drop;
            ct state { established, related } accept
            log prefix "nftables forward dropped: " flags all counter packets 0 bytes 0 drop
    }

    chain output {
            type filter hook output priority filter; policy drop;
            ct state { established, related } accept
            ip protocol icmp icmp type echo-request accept
            ip protocol icmp icmp type echo-request ip daddr 127.0.0.1 accept
            icmpv6 type echo-request accept
            ip protocol { tcp, udp } th dport 53 accept
            tcp dport 123 accept
            tcp dport { 80, 443 } accept
            tcp dport { 25, 465, 587, 993, 995, 4190 } accept
    }

    chain prerouting {
            type nat hook prerouting priority dstnat; policy accept;
    }

    chain postrouting {
            type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
    }

}

I suspect you also have some other FW software installed and managing Linux kernel firewall rules and probably overwriting whatever you are directly installing with nftables. Please make sure nftables is THE ONLY running firewall service.

The problem is insufficient access for ICMP on the output side. Not something I expected to give problems for input. But that's my lack of sufficient understanding of IPv6. For IPv6, routing relies on ICMP communications, unlike IPv4 which uses ARP.
Copying the ICMP line from the input chain to the output chain fixes the problem. I'm not certain if the list of types is ideal, but it is enough to get things working.

RFC 4890, Recommendations for Filtering ICMPv6 Messages in Firewalls

I'm not sure what is the cause of the problem but some of these suggestions may help:

At least for troubleshooting phase I suggest adding a log rule at the end of the output chain.

In most cases you need to allow the local interface in the output chain, usually after the ct state { established, related } accept rule:
oif lo counter accept

In the input chain you can allow both ip6 and ip access to port 25 by
tcp dport 25 counter accept

Counters can be very helpful in troubleshooting, so I suggest adding them to all the rules.


